# Run oracle image in gitlab pipeline

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, oracle19c

I want to run the oracle DB along with project, so I have an oracle image that i'm using as service image and my project's image as the base image. Both these image reside in AWS ECR.

```
test:
  stage: test
  image: ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/project:latest
  services:
    - name: ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/oracle-db:latest
      alias: oracleDB
  tags:
    - [runner]
```

I get the below message in logs -

```
*** WARNING: Service runner-3d2f0-***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com__oracle-db-0 probably didn't start properly.
Health check error:
service "runner-3d2f0-***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com__oracle-db-0-wait-for-service" health check: exit code 1
Health check container logs:
2021-09-23T03:44:16.658615888Z FATAL: No HOST or PORT found
```

However if I do `docker run ***.dkr.ecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/oracle-db:latest` I see that the oracle container has successfully launched.

Is there any problem with the runner? Or is there any other way to run both the applications and connect them somehow? Kindly help, new to world of gitlab. Thanks!